# how to get a sorted result in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to get a sorted result from a MySQL query and i dont have any idea of making the query.

I have a example Mysql table as follows :

```
     id | cat_type
     1  |  free
     2  |  free
     3  |  free
     4  |  free
     5  |  paid
     6  |  paid
    ... |  ...
    ... |  ...
    ... |  ...
   and it goes on.
```

The result should be as follows from the above table :

```
     id | cat_type
     1  | free 
     2  | free 
     5  | paid

     3  | free 
     4  | free 
     6  | paid

    ... | free
    ... | free
    ... | paid
  and goes on(should be sorted)
```

The total result should be splitted as 3. In the first three result, first two should be `free` and the next one should be `paid` likewise all the remaining result should be sorted as two `free` and one `paid`.

Any idea how to accomplish this using a query?

NOTE : The most important is that it should be sorted as two free and one paid. Not by ID.

Thanks.

Comment: Do it in php,mysql was nor designed for complicated order with groups.

Comment: i can accomplish using php but i need to do it in mysql query @Mihai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you particular data, you could do:

```
order by (case when cat_type = 'free' then id*1.0
               else 2*id - 7.5
          end)
```

This seems *very* arcane.  If you have a more general problem, you should ask another question, giving a better description of what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the answer @GordonLinoff.  Incase the table has more records, how to get the sorted result.