# Mysql sorting table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

In reference with my previous question - [how to get a sorted result in mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476371/how-to-get-a-sorted-result-in-mysql-query)

I am trying to get a sorted result of a table from a MySQL query.

The Table without sorting is as follows :

```
+---------+---------------+
|      id |      cat_type |  
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |          free |
|       2 |          free |
|       3 |          free |
|       4 |          paid |
|       5 |          paid |
|       6 |          free |
|       7 |          free |
|       8 |          free |
|       9 |          paid |
|      10 |          free |
|      11 |          free |
|      12 |          free |
|      13 |          paid |
|      14 |          free |
+---------+---------------+
```

The Sorted Table must be as follows :

```
+---------+---------------+
|      id |      cat_type |  
+---------+---------------+
|       1 |          free |
|       2 |          free |
|       4 |          paid |

|       3 |          free |
|       6 |          free |
|       5 |          paid |

|       7 |          free |
|       8 |          free |
|       9 |          paid |

|      10 |          free |
|      11 |          free |
|      13 |          paid |

|      12 |          free |
|      14 |          free |
+---------+---------------+
```

TASK : All the records are seperated by 3 for clarity and it should be sorted by column `cat_type` and not by `id`. The `cat_type` must be ordered by `free`, `free` and `paid`(Refer 2nd table column records.)

NOTE : The table is dynamic and has 'n' number of records.

How can i accomplish this with a mysql query ?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you're having problems.

Comment: sorry @JayBlanchard. I have tried with only six records of a static table with the following code : `order by (case when cat_type = 'free' then id*1.0
               else 2*id - 7.5
          end)` see this link of my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476371/how-to-get-a-sorted-result-in-mysql-query

Comment: Can you setup a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Same query again? Haven't you already asked this question today, or was it someone else from the same class???

Comment: @jarlh . . . This is a different question.  The other question was considerably less broad.

Comment: @JayBlanchard. SQL Fiddle site is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for my question and it works well for me.

The following code did the trick :

```
SET @i := 0; 
SET @j := 0.5; 
SELECT id, cat_type FROM 
(SELECT @i := @i + 1 as ordering, id, cat_type FROM table_name WHERE cat_type = 'free' 
 UNION 
 SELECT @j := @j + 2 as ordering, id, cat_type FROM table_name WHERE cat_type = 'paid') 
AS base_table 
ORDER BY ordering;
```

Works like charm. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate the rows for free and paid.  Probably the easiest way to enumerate two categories is with `union all`.  Then you can do arithmetic to get the "free" records first, and then the "paid" records.  I think this will do it:

```
select id, cat_type
from ((select t.*, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as seqnum
       from table t cross join (select @rn1 := 0) vars
       where cat_type = 'free'
       order by id
      ) union all
      (select t.*, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as seqnum
       from table t cross join (select @rn2 := 0) vars
       where cat_type = 'paid'
       order by id
      )
     ) t
order by (case when cat_type = 'free' then seqnum*1.0 else 2 * seqnum + 0.5 end)
```

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias